# Aggregate a column based on month range criteria from other column

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, data-manipulation

I've a table as Under:

```
+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| CUSTOMER |  BILL_DT   | DELIVERY_DT | UNITS |
+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| A        | 2007-12-07 | 2008-11-04  |     1 |
| A        | 2012-11-21 | 2013-01-31  |     1 |
| A        | 1992-12-11 | 1993-05-18  |     1 |
| A        | 2018-09-06 | 2019-05-28  |     1 |
| A        | 2004-11-29 | 2005-10-07  |     1 |
| B        | 2003-02-27 | 2004-03-22  |     1 |
| B        | 2017-11-13 | 2018-10-19  |     1 |
| B        | 2018-04-07 | 2018-05-18  |     2 |
| B        | 2019-06-18 | 2019-11-25  |     1 |
| C        | 2018-05-18 | 2018-08-11  |     1 |
| C        | 2018-03-16 | 2018-05-30  |     1 |
| C        | 2006-12-22 | 2007-08-17  |     1 |
+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

I wish to aggregate the UNITS based on the `bill_dt` and `delivery_dt`.

So for `February 2020` my criteria would be:

```
df %>%
  group_by(CUSTOMER) %>%
  filter(
    BILL_DT>='2009-01-01' & BILL_DT<='2020-02-29',
    DELIVERY_DT>= '2020-02-29'| is.na(DELIVERY_DT)
  ) %>%
  summarize(sumiv=sum(UNITS),
            DATE= format(as.Date('2020-02-01', "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m"))
```

For `Jan 2020` it would be

```
df %>%
  group_by(CUSTOMER) %>%
  filter(
    BILL_DT>='2009-01-01' & BILL_DT<='2020-01-31',
    DELIVERY_DT>= '2020-01-31'| is.na(DELIVERY_DT)
  ) %>%
  summarize(sumiv=sum(UNITS),
            DATE= format(as.Date('2020-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m"))
```

I wish to repeat this until `DATE = 2019-02` and then to bind all of them together.

Is there a way to loop to get the result? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

date.end.month <- seq(from = as.Date("2009-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-03-01"), by = "months")-1

bill_dev <- function(theDate) {
  df %>%
    filter(BILL_DT>='2009-01-01') %>%
    group_by(CUSTOMER) %>%
    filter(
      BILL_DT <= theDate,
      DELIVERY_DT >= theDate | is.na(DELIVERY_DT)
    ) %>%
    summarize(sumiv=sum(UNITS),
              DATE= format(theDate, "%Y-%m"))
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(date.end.month, bill_dev)) %>%
  arrange(CUSTOMER, DATE) %>%
  print(n=32)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 32 x 3
   CUSTOMER sumiv DATE   
   <chr>    <int> <chr>  
 1 A            1 2012-11
 2 A            1 2012-12
 3 A            1 2013-01
 4 A            1 2018-09
 5 A            1 2018-10
 6 A            1 2018-11
 7 A            1 2018-12
 8 A            1 2019-01
 9 A            1 2019-02
10 A            1 2019-03
11 A            1 2019-04
12 B            1 2017-11
13 B            1 2017-12
14 B            1 2018-01
15 B            1 2018-02
16 B            1 2018-03
17 B            3 2018-04
18 B            1 2018-05
19 B            1 2018-06
20 B            1 2018-07
21 B            1 2018-08
22 B            1 2018-09
23 B            1 2019-06
24 B            1 2019-07
25 B            1 2019-08
26 B            1 2019-09
27 B            1 2019-10
28 C            1 2018-03
29 C            1 2018-04
30 C            1 2018-05
31 C            1 2018-06
32 C            1 2018-07
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(CUSTOMER = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), BILL_DT = structure(c(13854, 15665, 
8380, 17780, 12751, 12110, 17483, 17628, 18065, 17669, 17606, 
13504), class = "Date"), DELIVERY_DT = structure(c(14187, 15736, 
8538, 18044, 13063, 12499, 17823, 17669, 18225, 17754, 17681, 
13742), class = "Date"), UNITS = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map2` to loop over the list of two vectors and do the `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
map2_dfr(head(dates1, -1) tail(dates2 -1), ~  
      df %>%
         group_by(CUSTOMER) %>%
         filter(BILL_DT>= '2009-01-01' & BILL_DT<=.x,
                DELIVERY_DT>= .x| is.na(DELIVERY_DT)
          ) %>%
        summarize(sumiv=sum(UNITS),
           DATE= format(.y, "%Y-%m"))) %>%
      arrange(CUSTOMER, DATE)
```

#### data

```
dates1 <- seq(as.Date('2019-02-01'), length.out = 14, by = '1 month')
dates2 <- dates1 - day(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` package:

```
df <- structure(list(CUSTOMER = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), BILL_DT = structure(c(13854, 15665, 
8380, 17780, 12751, 12110, 17483, 17628, 18065, 17669, 17606, 
13504), class = "Date"), DELIVERY_DT = structure(c(14187, 15736, 
8538, 18044, 13063, 12499, 17823, 17669, 18225, 17754, 17681, 
13742), class = "Date"), UNITS = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")


start_end <- seq(as.Date("2009-02-01"), as.Date("2019-03-01"), by = "months") - 1
start_end <- setNames(format(start_end, "%Y-%m"), start_end)

library(data.table)
df2 <- setDT(df)[BILL_DT >= '2009-01-01']

rbindlist(
  lapply(names(start_end), function(x) {
    df2[BILL_DT <= x & (DELIVERY_DT >= x | is.na(DELIVERY_DT))
        ][, .(sumiv = sum(UNITS), DATE = start_end[x]), CUSTOMER]
  })
)

#     CUSTOMER sumiv    DATE
#  1:        A     1 2012-11
#  2:        A     1 2012-12
#  3:        A     1 2013-01
#  4:        B     1 2017-11
#  5:        B     1 2017-12
#  6:        B     1 2018-01
#  7:        B     1 2018-02
#  8:        B     1 2018-03
#  9:        C     1 2018-03
# 10:        B     3 2018-04
# 11:        C     1 2018-04
# 12:        B     1 2018-05
# 13:        C     1 2018-05
# 14:        B     1 2018-06
# 15:        C     1 2018-06
# 16:        B     1 2018-07
# 17:        C     1 2018-07
# 18:        B     1 2018-08
# 19:        A     1 2018-09
# 20:        B     1 2018-09
# 21:        A     1 2018-10
# 22:        A     1 2018-11
# 23:        A     1 2018-12
# 24:        A     1 2019-01
# 25:        A     1 2019-02
```